# Cannot access to firebase script: Blocked by CORS policy

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add these libs to my app.

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-app.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.2/firebase-database.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The server is run on localhost.
But the console says it cannot access the script to CORS policy. I searched and tried all solutions but nothing worked. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The server doesn't allow CORS access to those scripts, so either stop asking for CORS access (remove the `crossorigin` attribute) or reconfigure the server to grant permission with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on how to apply this in the cloud function.